# Sub array Collections not showing with foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I have blade view that is to show a list based on selection from the parent list just like selecting a category to present the list of subcategories. It was working perfectly well before but I suddenly discovered that instead of the child list to be showing, it is the parent that is showing instead.

Parent Blade View

```
<section class="only-banner pt--20 pb--20 bg__white">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="tab-content another-product-style">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="#">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="ptb--10 pl--20">
                                <h2><strong>Categories</strong></h2>
                            </div>
                        @foreach($categories as $cat)
                            <div class="product-slider-active2">
                                <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 card">
                                    <div class="card" style="border-radius:10px; box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(154,160,185,0.5), 0 15px 40px rgba(166,173,201,.2);">
                                        <div class="product justify-content-center">
                                            <div class="product__inner pr--30 pl--30">
                                                <div class="pro__thumb pt--30">
                                                    <a href="{{ url('/category-list/'.$cat->id) }}">
                                                    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset('/images/category/medium/'.$cat->image) }}" alt="category images">
                                                </a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-body justify-content-center pb--30">
                                                <div class="product__details">
                                                    <h2><a href="{{ url('/category-list/'.$cat->id) }}">{{$cat->name}}</a></h2>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                        </div>                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Child Blade view

```
@extends('layout.frontLayouts.design')
@section('content')
        <section class="htc__product__area ptb--50 bg__white">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="product-style-tab">
                            <div class="product-tab-list">
                                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-content another-product-style">
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="#">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        @foreach($categories as $cat)
                                        <div class="pl--20 pr--20 ptb--10" style="display:flex; justify-content: center;">
                                        <h2><strong>{{ $cat->name }}</strong></h2>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
                                        <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
                                        </div>
                                            @foreach($cat->categories as $subcat)
                                            @if($subcat->status==1)
                                        <div class="product-slider-active2">
                                            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
                                                <div class="card justify-content-center" style="border-radius:10px; box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(154,160,185,0.5), 0 15px 40px rgba(166,173,201,.2);">
                                                    <div class="product justify-content-center">
                                                        <div class="product__inner pr--50 pl--50">
                                                            <div class="pro__thumb pt--30">
                                                                <a href="{{ asset('products/'.$subcat->url) }}">
                                                                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset('/images/category/medium/'.$subcat->image) }}" alt="category images">
                                                            </a>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="card-body justify-content-center pb--30">
                                                            <div class="product__details pl--10 pr--10">
                                                                <h2><a href="{{ asset('products/'.$subcat->url) }}">{{$subcat->name}}</a></h2>
                                                            </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                            @endif
                                            @endforeach
                                        @endforeach
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
@endsection
```

My Controller

```
public function categoryList($id=null) {
        $categories_menu = "";
        $categories = Category::with('categories')->where('id',$id)->get();
        $categories = json_decode(json_encode($categories));

        return view('pages.category')->with(compact('categories_menu','categories'));
    }
```

I don't know what the issue can be

Comment: Random question, what is the purpose of `$categories = json_decode(json_encode($categories));`? Do you really need to turn a collection of objects into an array of objects?

Comment: Yes, I prefer it that way for debug purposes